# In Haskell, how do I promptly close resources?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

Old `pipes` [tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-2.1.0/docs/Control-Frame-Tutorial.html) has following example. How would this code look like with version 4.1.1?

```
  read' :: FilePath -> Frame Text IO C C ()
  read' file = do
      liftU $ putStrLn "Opening file..."
      h <- liftU $ openFile file ReadMode
      -- The following requires "import qualified Control.Monad as M"
      finallyD (putStrLn "Closing file ..." M.>> hClose h) $ readFile' h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent function is `readFile` from `Pipes.Safe.Prelude`, which you can find [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-safe-2.1.0/docs/Pipes-Safe-Prelude.html#v%3areadFile).  I've pasted the source below for reference:

```
withFile :: MonadSafe m => FilePath -> IO.IOMode -> (IO.Handle -> m r) -> m r
withFile file ioMode = bracket (liftIO $ IO.openFile file ioMode) (liftIO . IO.hClose)

readFile :: MonadSafe m => FilePath -> Producer' String m ()
readFile file = withFile file IO.ReadMode P.fromHandle
```